# How to create a counter in XSLT which increases by 1 foreach loop , i have nested foreach loop

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="Quote">
<Quote>    

        <xsl:for-each select="Configuration"> 
            <ConfigItem>
                <xsl:variable name="GeneratedStructure">
                <xsl:variable name="ConfigurationPos" select="position()+10"/> 
                <configurationPostion><xsl:value-of select = "$ConfigurationPos" /> </configurationPostion> 
                <!--  <VariableValue><xsl:value-of select="$ConfigurationPos"/></VariableValue>-->
                <Vendor><xsl:value-of select="Vendor" /></Vendor>
                <PriceListID><xsl:value-of select="PriceListID" /></PriceListID>
                <Source><xsl:value-of select="Source" /></Source>
                <xsl:for-each select="ProductLineItem">
                    <ProductLineItem>
                        <xsl:variable name="ProductPos" select="$ConfigurationPos+(position()*10)"/>
                        <ProductPostionNumber><xsl:value-of select = "$ProductPos" /></ProductPostionNumber>
                    </ProductLineItem>   
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>  
                <xsl:variable name="SubtotalPos" select="max($GeneratedStructure/ProductLineItem/ProductPostionNumber)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$GeneratedStructure"/> 
                <xsl:variable name="max">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$GeneratedStructure/ProductLineItem/ProductPostionNumber">
                        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <subMax><xsl:value-of select = "number($max)+10" /></subMax>
            </ConfigItem>
        </xsl:for-each>  
</Quote>
</xsl:template>
```

How to create a counter in XSLT which increases by 1 foreach loop , i have a foreach loop inside a foreach loop , i had written it but once the parent foreach loop starts for next iteration the counter is set to zero

Comment: `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. Usually you can use the 'position()' function to index the nodes being processed. Please add a [mcve] showing input and expected result to your question.

Comment: <Quote>
 <Configuration>
  <RowID>12333dddd</RowID>
   <ProductLineItem>
      <LineNumber>1.0.1</LineNumber>
      </ProductLineItem>
   <ProductLineItem>
        <LineNumber>2.0.1</LineNumber>
       </ProductLineItem>
</Configuration>
 <Configuration>
  <RowID>12ss333dddd</RowID>
  <ProductLineItem>
   <LineId>5165550509</LineId>
  </ProductLineItem>
 </Configuration>
</Quote>

Comment: Added sample XML file

Comment: Please don't post code in comments . Edit your question and add the code there. And show the expected result too.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Quote>
    <ConfigItem>
        <configurationPostion>1</configurationPostion>
        <ProductLineItem>
            <ProductPostionNumber>2</ProductPostionNumber>
        </ProductLineItem>
        <ProductLineItem>
            <ProductPostionNumber>3</ProductPostionNumber>
        </ProductLineItem>
        </ConfigItem>
    <ConfigItem>
        <configurationPostion>5</configurationPostion>
        <ProductLineItem>
            <ProductPostionNumber>6</ProductPostionNumber>
        </ProductLineItem>
    </ConfigItem>
</Quote>

Comment: is the Desired output, i am not able to add it in the samples as it is getting formatting issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If - as it seems - you want to number both parent and child using the same sequence, then try using `xsl:number`. For example:

**XML**

```
<Quote>
   <Configuration>
      <RowID>12333dddd</RowID>
      <ProductLineItem>
         <LineNumber>1.0.1</LineNumber>
      </ProductLineItem>
      <ProductLineItem>
         <LineNumber>2.0.1</LineNumber>
      </ProductLineItem>
   </Configuration>
   <Configuration>
      <RowID>12ss333dddd</RowID>
      <ProductLineItem>
         <LineId>5165550509</LineId>
      </ProductLineItem>
   </Configuration>
</Quote>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Quote">
    <Quote>    
        <xsl:for-each select="Configuration"> 
            <ConfigItem>
                <configurationPostion>
                    <xsl:number count="Configuration | ProductLineItem" level="any"/>
                </configurationPostion>
                <xsl:for-each select="ProductLineItem">
                    <ProductPostionNumber>
                        <xsl:number count="Configuration | ProductLineItem" level="any"/>
                    </ProductPostionNumber>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ConfigItem>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </Quote>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Quote>
  <ConfigItem>
    <configurationPostion>1</configurationPostion>
    <ProductPostionNumber>2</ProductPostionNumber>
    <ProductPostionNumber>3</ProductPostionNumber>
  </ConfigItem>
  <ConfigItem>
    <configurationPostion>4</configurationPostion>
    <ProductPostionNumber>5</ProductPostionNumber>
  </ConfigItem>
</Quote>
```